# is this $f(x)$ continuous at almost every point of an interval $[a, b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, almost-everywhere

I think a function having removable discontinuities is continuous at almost every point of an interval $[a, b]$.

For example, let $f$ be a function by \begin{align}f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin(x) & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \\ 10 & x=0\end{cases}\end{align}

---

How about a function having jump discontinuities?

For example, let $g$ be a function by
\begin{align}g(x)=\begin{cases}x^2 & x\lt0 \\ 1 & x=0 \\2-x^2 &x\gt 0\end{cases}\end{align}

Is this function $g$ also continuous at almost every point of an interval $[-1, 1]$?

Comment: Of course, why not?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you. Guessing from your answer, continuity of the function only depends on the measure of domain of the function not on the measure of the function, isn't it?